# Getting document for signing from S3

Tags: docusignapi

I have documents stored in S3 and would like to send them to docusign via REST API. I am using ruby and the standard net/http library (or Faraday, or docusign_rest gem). When sending fromS3 I am getting an error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED",
  "message": "The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. Bytes for document corresponding to documentId 13 not found in request. 'documentId=<x>' possibly missing from Content-Disposition header."
}
```

I am hosting on Heroku so no local storage access.

Here is some relevant code...

```
remote_file = Faraday.get(document.filepicker_policy_url)
```

This retrieves the document from S3, then

```
post_body << remote_file.body
```

This should add it to the multi-part post.

Comment: can you get it to work from a local file?  If so you might try downloading the file from s3 into a ruby tempfile and then uploading from there

Comment: Awesome! And it allows me to use the docusign_rest gem which wants a local file, so no monkeying about with net/http or Faraday. Submit as an answer and I will give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a ruby tempfile, and then upload from there

Comment: Awesome! And it allows me to use the docusign_rest gem which wants a local file, so no monkeying about with net/http or Faraday.

Comment: Have you looked into the paper clip gem?  It seems like you already have the s3 stuff locked down, but I use this gem and it's amazing for attaching files to active records with ease. http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip

Comment: Yeah, I am using Filepicker for uploads, but will probably be moving away from it. I have used paperclip with good success before.